# Using of qDebug() or printf() with Qt Creater, Cmake, MSVS and CDB- debugger

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake, windbg

Is it possible to use qDebug() or printf() to plot log-messages in a qt-GUI-Program with Qt Creater, Cmake, MSVS and CDB- debugger? I’m trying to use them but unfortunately I get no messages in the Qt Creater Application Output window.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to print log messages in a Qt-GUI application run from Qt Creator? I don't understand how MSVS and CDB- debugger relate to the rest of the question...

For the first part yes, you can place your logs using both qDebug and printf to stdout and Qt Creator should show those. Otherwise, try to start your application from the command line and see if there you can see the logs.

Comment: I create my Qt-project with cmake and compile my Qt-Program in VS-2010-compiler and that is the problem in my case.

Comment: Then what do Qt Creator and gdb have to do with this? Run your application from the command line and see if your logs are shown.

Comment: "Then what do Qt Creator and gdb have to do with this?" I work in Qt Creator. In Qt Creator it is possible to choose between qmake and cmake and between gdb and cdb.